# Finding the probability to reach destination

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

I got the answer to the first part as 1/4 which is correct but the solution tells it to solve by a recursive approach and I've no idea how to do that. I'm guessing I got the answer just by luck so it'd be great if someone can post the correct approaches for the question. Thanks

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: Taking the two cases for the first part:
1/3* 1/4 + 1/3*1/2

I couldn't solve the second part

Comment: I'm guessing that's what the book means by a recursive approach (examining all of the possible routes that lead to $A$ and figuring out each of their probabilities). So, I'm pretty sure you did it "properly" as your reasoning is certainly correct. Did you need help on the second one?

Comment: I think I am getting where my approach was wrong. Suppose say, at R2 we actually have three paths to choose from rather than 2. Similarly at R3 there are 5 paths rather than 4 to choose from. I just need to write this recursively for both the parts of question and I'm unable to do so

Comment: Do you know whether the bicyclist can retrace her steps? Every problem I've seen like this says no (but it usually does that explicitly). You're probably right though.

Comment: yeah it isn't mentioned in the question but I think she can retrace her steps. Can you tell how to form the relation in such cases?

Answer (score 1):

My notion is that travel on the tree is in general moving from the root P to the terminal leaves $\rm R_{11}$, $\rm R_{12}$, $\rm R_{21}$, $\rm R_{32}$, $\rm R_{33}$, and $\rm R_{34}$. I'd propose that you can go either way along $\rm R_2\rm R_3$ and pass through $\rm A$ *once*. So the paths through the network are:

$\rm {PR}_1\rm R_{11}$, $\rm {PR}_1\rm R_{12}$, $\rm {PR}_2\rm R_{21}$, $\rm {PR}_2\rm A \rm R_{3} \rm R_{32}$, $\rm {PR}_2\rm A \rm R_{3} \rm R_{33}$, $\rm {PR}_2\rm A \rm R_{3} \rm R_{34}$, $\rm {PR}_3\rm A \rm R_{2} \rm R_{21}$, $\rm {PR}_3 \rm R_{32}$, $\rm {PR}_3 \rm R_{33}$, and $\rm {PR}_3 \rm R_{34}$.

Swirling through the numbers:

- Terminal nodes $\rm R_{11}$ and $\rm R_{12}$ are reached with probability 1/6.
- Terminal node $\rm R_{21}$ is reached with probability 1/4.
- Terminal nodes $\rm R_{32}$, $\rm R_{33}$ and $\rm R_{34}$ are reached with probability 5/36.

**(QUESTION 1)** As uzumaki noted the probability of passing through A is 1/4.

**(QUESTION 2)** Given that you pass through A, the probability of having passed on $\rm{PR}_3$ is 1/3, and the probability of having passed on $\rm{PR}_2$ is 2/3.

The idea of recursion is that you work the probabilities from the leaves to the root rather than vice versa.

- For terminal nodes $\rm R_{11}$ and $\rm R_{12}$ it really doesn't make any difference which way you calculate along the tree.
- Looking at node $\rm R_2$ however, it is easier to calculate from the leaves as the sum of $\rm R_2 \rm P + \rm R_2\rm{AR}_3\rm P$  than it is to calculate starting from P.